# Alternative ways to implement Data-Driven Testing for Selenium 3.0?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, testng, data-driven

Currently I am using Selenium 3.0 with the TestNG framework and a page factory setup for maintaining the page setup. I have been using wini for fetching data from the text file using section and option name.

- What are alternative ways for a Data-Driven approach?
- How can use I them for running same test case but with different set of data?

Please elaborate with examples
Here is how i am currently accessing it with section and option name.

```
   @BeforeClass (alwaysRun=true)
   public void setup(ITestContext context) throws Exception{
            ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
            File file = new File(classLoader.getResource("datafile.txt").getFile());
            crmdatafile = new ReadData(file.getAbsolutePath());                          
   }

   @Test   
   public void setcontact(){
     Section section= crmdatafile.data.get("Contact_Buyer");                                                                                                                             
     ContactsPage.Select_Profile_Title(section.get("Title"));
     ContactsPage.Select_Profile_Contactlanguage(section.get("Contact_language")); 
   }
```

This is how i have been fetching data from wini data text file where my datafile looks like

```
[Contact_Buyer]
Title = Madam
Contact_language = French    
etc
```

how can i achieve this using dataprovider to pass multiple values(many section and option names)

Comment: I have re-worded your question slightly so that it leads to less "opinionated" answers. Could you link to this wini library you are talking about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using TestNG have a look at [DataProviders](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parameters-dataproviders). This way you can repeat a test for each data point you have.

Example code:

```
public static var data:Array = [ [ 0, 0 ], [ 1, 2 ], [ 2, 4 ] ];

[Test( dataProvider="data")]
public function doubleTest( value1:int, value2:int ):void {
    assertEquals( value1, value2 * 2 );
}
```

If non-technical users need to update the data you could later move the data:Array to another source, like Excel or a Wiki-table (e.g. [FitNesse](http://www.fitnesse.org/)).

Comment: I have added details on how i fetch the data from text file using wini, let me know how this can be achieved with dataprovider. Data proivder can  pass section names , currently achieved by Section section= crmdatafile.data.get("Contact_Buyer"); and Section section= crmdatafile.data.get("Contact_owner"); now my testcase will read 2 keysets and run the same test twice with the values inside the keyset

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like how the faker Gem does with locales?

https://github.com/stympy/faker

example like: https://github.com/stympy/faker/blob/master/lib/locales/ca.yml

Have you different data sets as diff yml files and based on environment it picks the dif yml?